# How can you insert/extract items in/from a specific inventory slot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

I know it is possible, but I have no idea whether it is an add-on or just some undocumented vanilla method (the turtle api can't be used for that, apparently).

Comment: In what context are you talking about?

Comment: taking items from specific slot from, let's say, a chest into the 'local' inv of the turtle, and putting it into a specific slot from some machine

Comment: You can set the slot in the turtle with `turtle.select([slotNum])`, but I don't see a way of setting the slot of the target chest or other tile entity block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible directly, but if you know that all slots will always be full, or which item you are looking for, you can keep using `suck()` until you hit the right slot (in the former case), or you find the right item (in the latter).

Comment: I am pretty sure it is possible, maybe the functionality was added by an addon? one of the reasons I want this is to manage my personal inventory through the random things player interface, where I'd need free slots between items, which would not be possible with just suck/drop

Comment: edit: seems like i confused computercraft and openComputers, my bad.

Comment: You could use OpenPeripheral.